# Automate Non default windows application / Java apps using pywinauto

Tags: c#, python, pywinauto

I need to automate non default windows applications like Oracle VM Virtual Box , wireshark etc

Swapy is listing menu items and its accessibilities only for deault windows applications like notepad but for wireshark its giving menu items as NULL and even through invoking menuItem function its returning no menu item error.

Any help in automating java based applications?
Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Box looks like QT-based app. Any way pywinauto can't automate it. There are pyQT package and [robot framework](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework). More unified way is using Windows UI Automation API (UIA) or UIA-based [TestStack.White](http://teststack.net/White/) framework (written in C#).